# Table text overlaps while using p

Tags: tables

I am trying to write a table with **11 columns** with some numerical data. But texts of some cells overlap the next cell. I am using `p{\dimexpr.09\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}` to control the width of each column and `\small` font size. Thanks in Advance. The MWE is

```
\documentclass[3p, final]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{skip=0pt,singlelinecheck=off}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\journal{Applied Soft Computing}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[!htb]
        \label{tab3}
        \caption{table 3}
        \small
        \begin{tabular}{@{}p{\dimexpr.09\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}p{\dimexpr.09\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}p{\dimexpr.09\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}p{\dimexpr.09\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}p{\dimexpr.09\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}p{\dimexpr.09\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}p{\dimexpr.09\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}p{\dimexpr.09\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}p{\dimexpr.09\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}p{\dimexpr.09\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}p{\dimexpr.09\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}@{}}
            \toprule
            Server             & \textbf{Dionaea} & \textbf{Cowrie} & \textbf{Heralding} & \textbf{Honeytrap} & \textbf{Rdpy} & \textbf{Adbhoney} & \textbf{Mailoney} & \textbf{Tanner} & \textbf{Conpot} & \textbf{Total Alert} \\ \midrule
            \textbf{Africa}    & 65464665         & 846132         & 86124            & 89645446            & 985131        & 95621455             & 956465              & 8465            & 65465            & 865135665645             \\
            \textbf{Australia}       & 86465          & 865465          & 8665             & 656165             & 864565         & 989230              & 9846465              & 6548465           & 9846516            & 8746563              \\ \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your table is with normal font size wider than text width, so you need to reduce font size in it to `\footnotesize`. Also I suggest to use `S` columns defined in the `siunitx` package for columns with numbers:

```
\documentclass[3p, final]{elsarticle}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{skip=0pt,singlelinecheck=off}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\journal{Applied Soft Computing}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[!htb]
\caption{table 3}
\label{tab3}
    \footnotesize
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \sisetup{tight-spacing,
             group-four-digits}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l 
        S[table-format=8.0]
        S[table-format=6.0]
        S[table-format=5.0]
        S[table-format=8.0]
        S[table-format=6.0]
        S[table-format=8.0]
        S[table-format=7.0]
        S[table-format=7.0]
        S[table-format=7.0]
        S[table-format=12.0]
                             }
    \toprule
Server  & \mc{Dionaea}  & \mc{Cowrie}   & \mc{Heralding}    & \mc{Honeytrap}
        & \mc{Rdpy}     & \mc{Adbhoney} & \mc{Mailoney}     & \mc{Tanner}
        & \mc{Conpot}   & \mc{Total Alert}  \\ 
    \midrule
Africa
        & 65464665      & 846132        & 86124             & 89645446
        & 985131        & 95621455      & 956465            & 8465
        & 65465         & 865135665645             \\
Australia
        & 86465         & 865465        & 8665              & 656165
        & 864565        & 989230        & 9846465           & 6548465
        & 9846516       & 8746563              \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines shows text borders)

Comment: thanks for Your time. All my tables are left aligned except this one, any way to make this left aligned

Comment: @MAzharulIslam, sorry, I do not understand your comment. What is left aligned? Table width is equal to text width, so it is in text from left border to the right one. However, it is not clear, what present your table. To my opinion, proposed solution for your  table is very consistent and easy to red.

Comment: sorry, I should have made it clear. every column's text should be left aligned like the first column

Comment: @MAzharulIslam, then replace `S` column specifiers with `l` and remove all `\mc` commands.

Comment: its working now. Really appreciate Your help